# Как вставить переменную в текст при подключении Title и description в 1С-Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс, переменные

Помогите написать рабочий код для плаформы 1С-Битрикс.

При редактировании файла "index.php" нужно в Title и description, чтобы подставлялась переменная из файла который подключается перед этим. Пример кода:

```
<?include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/сайт/подключаемый файл.php");?>

<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("(вставить переменную из подключаемого файла выше) заголовок страницы");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", "Описание страницы (вставить переменную из подключаемого файла выше)");
?>

Текст страницы...

<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("$переменная заголовок страницы");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", "Описание страницы $переменная");
```